# card game : win play

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3

I'm currently developing a card game using Actionscript 3, and I was wondering how to be sure that there at least one win possibility.

The game has similar gameplay to this one :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameduell.cleopatraspyramidnew&hl=en 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cleopatras-pyramid/id401141292?mt=8

Player has to play a card that matchs the previous or the next value of the presented cards.

I tried different methods, but still not satisfied.

What I wanted to know, is how to be sure that in the hidden cards, there is at least one winning game, and so the player will have the possibility to win.

thanks

Comment: This highly depends on your game's rules and process, based on your description you can build a graph give that 2 cards are neighbors, meaning there is an edge between 2 cards, if one of them is the previous or the next of the other card

Answer (score 0):

Given all the cards are pre-placed, you can do the following:

1. Get a clear board. Pair up your set of cards, to get a set of pairs
2. Get one pair out of remaining set of pairs. If set is empty, provide filled board as the algorithm result.
3. Place both cards into your board to the next available positions, so that both places are available to pickup in the gameplay phase. If no places are available, this means you've placed previous pair(s) wrongly, so you have to retrack - pop state from stack, attempt another placement at that state.
4. Push state to stack.
5. Go to 2.

The trick is, you start with a board being won, and add a layer (a pair) so that removing this pair will lead to a winnable condition, by state sequence construction. Apparently, you can add random pairs to random available locations in your pyramid, and occasionally the random will be so that, for example, the last 2 places will not be both available to pick up during actual gameplay, and this is a situation to retract previous placement, maybe not just one. You can remedy this situation by giving depth value to grid spaces, and if max depth of free spaces equals the number of unplaced pairs, the deepest places are occupied instead of random.

If your game involves playing one card at a time, then an additional check should be performed at picking the next card - if the remaining set of cards becomes unconnected, e.g. you've picked all the 4's and there are both 3's and 5's left in unpicked set. This means you have to retract to select another card at previous stage. An algorithm can be like this:

1. Prepare empty grid, prepare set of cards to place.
2. Recursion entry point. If passed -1 (first time), select a full set of available cards. If not the first time, select a set of valid cards based on previously selected one (e.g. there was a 4, select all 3's, select all 5's, select all 4's if allowed). Shuffle the set.
   If the set is empty, and all available cards set is also empty, return from recursion with true, otherwise return false.
3. Select next card from the set. If none remain, fall back out of recursion with failure.
4. Check if removal of current card discontinues the remaining set of unplaced cards. If yes, go to 3.
5. Select an empty available place in the grid, place selected card there.
6. Enter recursion (save state, go to 2) with current card's value, updated grid and reduced set of unplaced cards.
7. If recursion result is false, retract action in 5, and go to 3. If true, leave recursion with true.